# Comparing two collections of objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 collections, one of available features and one of user features.  I would like to delete an item in the available features that contain the featurecode in the other collection but can't find the right syntax.

I've included my current code that doesn't compile (it's complaining that I can't use the "==" operator, my Linq knowledge is minimal)

Is Linq the best way to do this?  Any help would be appreciated.

```
        AvailableFeatureViewListClass availableFeatures = (AvailableFeatureViewListClass)uxAvailableList.ItemsSource;
        UserFeatureListClass userFeatures = (UserFeatureListClass)uxUserFeatureList.ItemsSource;

        foreach (UserFeatureClass feature in userFeatures)
        {
            availableFeatures.Remove(availableFeatures.First(FeatureCode => FeatureCode == feature.FeatureCode));
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Except` method with a custom `Equals` or `IEqualityComparer` implementation for your type (the type of your collection item is not really obvious):

```
var features = availableFeatures.Except(userFeatures, new FeatureCodeComparer());
```

If the `availableFeatures` is just a collection of integers, you'd just do something like:

```
var features = availableFeatures.Except(userFeatures.Select(x => x.FeatureCode));
```

Comment: I tried the second suggestion and it complains that the "x" part cannot be inferred.  Sounds like it should work but the Linq is throwing me right now.

Comment: @Mark: Could you tell us what the `AvailableFeatureViewListClass` or `UserFeatureListClass` types are? Why aren't you just using generic types directly?

Comment: Thanks Mehrdad, they are actually both BusinessObjects, but the items in the object collection share properties (in this case FeatureCode)

Comment: It looks weird that the compiler can't infer the type in an standard environment. But anyway, try changing the lambda to (TypeOfYourObjectGoesHere x) => x.FeatureCode

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
var features = (from af in availableFeatures select af.FeatureCode)
            .Intersect(from uf in userFeatures select uf.FeatureCode);
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, it looks right but when I try to bind nothing returns.  I checked and the features variable is cast to the IntersectIntegrator object, is there any way to convert that back to a AvailableFeatureViewList class?

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
    IEnumerable<int> a = new List<int>() { 1, 2 };
    IEnumerable<int> b = new List<int> { 2, 3 };

    var result = a.Except(b);
    a = result;
```